# how to make edits without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have edit.js.erb:

```
$('#danswerform_<%= @danswer.id %>').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

update.js.erb:

```
$('#edit_danswer').remove();
$('#danswerform_<%= @danswer.id %>').show();
```

and 
and edit form with `<%= form_for(@danswer, remote: true) do |f| %>`

but when I confirm the changes happening reload.( then I press edit all right)
controller:

```
  def update
    @danswer = Danswer.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @danswer.update_attributes(params[:danswer])
        format.html { redirect_to danswers_path, notice: 'Danswer was successfully updated.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you mean the page is reloaded when you submit the form, whereas it has `remote: true` ? You certainly have a javascript error in your page.

Comment: Yes, the page is reloaded when I  submit the form, This form is also used when adding a new record  and in this case is working properly

Comment: Aree with Baldrick -- check your javascript console for any errors. If there are none, than you may not have jquery_ujs being loaded

Comment: In javascript console there are none errors, and jquery_ujs I loaded. This form is also used when adding a new record and in this case is working properly!

Comment: Are you uploading any attachement file in the form?

Comment: No. As I realized the problem is that default routing for create - # POST /danswers, while for update - # PUT /danswers/:id, and after whet page redirect to /danswers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. On page I have 2 form with identical id: partial _danswer and _form when edit action(edit_danswer_id).. Thanks to all!